# how to return the value of the current resource group arm template

Tags: arm

I have the below code but want to replace the hard coded resource group name with the current resource group i'm deploying to. I place the value of the resource group  in Visual studio via the deploy to dialog box as shown in the picture "deploy dialog box".

In the below code I want to remove the hard coded name resourcegroupA and use the value I input into the dialog box from visual studio.

[image: deploy dialog box]

```
 {
  "apiVersion": "2016-03-30",
  "name": "[parameters('LoadBalancername')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/', parameters('LoadBalancerpublicIPAddressName'))]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "frontendIPConfigurations": [
      {
        "name": "LoadBalancerFrontEnd",
        "properties": {
          "publicIPAddress": {
            "id": "[resourceId('resourcegroupA', 'Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', parameters('LoadBalancerpublicIPAddressName'))]"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

worked it out you just need to remove the reference to the resource group in quotes , in the below example remove'resourcegroupA' and it will use the resource group name it is deploying to that you have selected through the visual studio dialog box!

"id": "[resourceId('resourcegroupA', 'Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', parameters('LoadBalancerpublicIPAddressName'))]"

change above to the below!

"id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', parameters('LoadBalancerpublicIPAddressName'))]"